# How check if is directory and set content in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

How to check if requested url is a directory and not a file, and if it is directory show a message (in my case a meta tag)

Currently I have this but it is not working properly:

```
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteRule "<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow'>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set content in `RewriteRule` but you can use this work-around by using a separate HTTP status for this:

```
# for a directory that is not a file redirect to status 226
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L,R=226]

# show custom content for status 226
ErrorDocument 226 "<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow'>"
```